# double sum in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to write this simple code for double sum in mathematica, but it had no answer to me

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Actually I want to write the square of the following series(n may be infinity) as a double sum.
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
Sum[a[i]*b[j-i],{j,0,n},{i,0,j}]
```

For more information on sum and products in mathematica, have a look at the documentation:

[Sum and products](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SumsAndProducts.html)

hope it helps

---

for your second question write:

```
(Sum[(-1)^(k-1)/k^t,{k,1,n}])^2
```

---

Not sure what your update is, but if it's about the infinity just type :

```
(Sum[(-1)^(k-1)/k^t,{k,1,Infinity}])^2
```

and if you want the numerical value type :

```
N[%]
```

and it will print you the numerical value of your sum

If you want to define a function :

```
f[n_]:= (Sum[(-1)^(k-1)/k^t,{k,1,n}])^2
```

---

the square as a double sum is :

```
Sum[(-1)^(i-1)/i^t*(-1)^(j-1)/j^t,{i,1,n},{i,1,n}]
```

and it should be equal with any n to the square `(Sum[(-1)^(k-1)/k^t,{k,1,n}])^2`

Comment: I want first this squre in the form of double series, then numerical value. because the numerical value, when I square it and when I write in the double series form, they are different. I think the limit of these forms are the same, but for finite case, No. thanks

Comment: @asd, do you mean replace in my first function a[i] by (-1)^(i-1)/i^t and b[i-j] by (-1)^((i-j)-1)/(i-j)^t ?

Comment: @asd were you able to find what you need ?